# Hibernate Criteria restriction on a not loaded table

Tags: sql, hibernate, select, constraints

I'm trying to have a Criteria query to have a restriction on an entity that isn't loaded.

My mapping is all done via one-to-many relations.

For example, I'm trying to get the following SQL query using criteria:

```
SELECT {msg.*} FROM Messages AS msg  
WHERE msg.source_key IN 
  ( SELECT ds.unique_key FROM Data_Sources AS ds " +
    WHERE ds.source_type_key IN " +
       ( SELECT dst.unique_key FROM Data_Source_types AS dst " +
          WHERE unique_name = 'RequiredName' ) )
```

Thus, I want to get Messages, with a restriction that is set on an entity that is not fetched by Hibernate. Currently, the best I could get is:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria( Message.class )
    .createAlias( "dataSource", "ds", CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN )
    .createAlias( "ds.sourceType", "type" )
    .add( Restrictions.eq( "type.name", "HL7GatewayServer" ) )
```

However, this query also loads the dataSource and dataSourceType.

EDIT: My mapping:

MESSAGES:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="messages", schema="mySchema") 
@SequenceGenerator(name="sequence",sequenceName="mySchema.local_key_sequence")
public class Message
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "unique_key")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequence")
    private long                     id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "source_key")
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = DataSource.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private DataSource               dataSource       = null;
    [...]
}
```

DATA_SOURCES:

```
@Entity
@Proxy(lazy = true)
@Table(name = "data_sources", schema = "mySchema")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence", sequenceName = "mySchema.local_key_sequence")
public class DataSource
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "unique_key")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequence")
    private long                      id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "source_type_key")
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = DataSourceType.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private DataSourceType            sourceType;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Message.class, mappedBy = "dataSource", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Message>             messages = new HashSet<Message>();

    [...]
}
```

DATA_SOURCE_TYPE:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="data_source_types", schema="mySchema") 
@SequenceGenerator(name="sequence",sequenceName="mySchema.local_key_sequence")
public class DataSourceType
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="unique_key", unique=true,nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="sequence")
    private long id; 

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=DataSource.class, mappedBy="sourceType",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<DataSource> dataSources = new HashSet<DataSource>(0);

    [...]
}
```

I managed to get this working in HQL, but 
is there a way to achieve this using Criteria?

Comment: what would you get in hibernate query when you run this. and also show your mapping.

Comment: All of my mappings are one-to-many.  When I run this, DataSource and DataSourceType objects are also fetched, something I want to avoid in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {

    crit = session.createCriteria(Message.class, "msg");
    crit.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    // UPDATE
    // Add your criteria sub query or any ...
}
```

and add `lazy='true'`

Comment: but how would then the restriction that `Message.DataSource.DataSourceType.unique_name == 'RequiredName'` apply?

Comment: nope - it still fetches the entities I don't want fetched.  `crit.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);` only sets the type of the resultset, but the other entities are also fetched and stored in the cache.

Comment: @Ravi Parekh: added the mapping

Comment: @iliaden you mean, criteria also load `(SELECT * FROM Data_Sources AS ds)` and you don't want to load that. am i?

Comment: most probably criteria won't load all but in your situation. :(
would you also give me DB table list i'll create it my side and then test.
mean while take a  look while executing `Criteria` see, what hibernate query gives.